Mid Air Point from Vuforia stopped working
I am with the basic version of Vuforia and I had developed an application in Unity with Vuforia's Mid Air Point. It used to work normally last month, but now it stopped working, how can I correct it? What was the cause?
Unity Version: 2022.3.30f1
Vuforia: com.ptc.vuforia.engine-10.22.5
I have tried updating the version of vuforia, even making a new project in Unity with Vuforia's Mid Air Point, with something simple like placing spheres in the air, but even so, it still doesn't work, why?

Please add some additional information. What device and platform are you using? Have you tried with the Vuforia Core Samples' Ground Plane scene? Ground Plane only works with ARCore/ARKit or Microsoft surface pro devices (Via VISLAM).
